# SFML VertexArray not member of sf

Tags: c++, sfml

I have the following program for drawing a triangle with vertex arrays, as described in SFML tutorials.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try{
        sf::RenderWindow Mywindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"TriColor Triangle!");


        sf::VertexArray triangle(sf::Triangles, 3);

        triangle[0].position = sf::Vector2f(5,5);
        triangle[1].position = sf::Vector2f(50,5);
        triangle[2].position = sf::Vector2f(50,50);

        triangle[0].color = sf::Color::Red;
        triangle[1].color = sf::Color::Blue;
        triangle[2].color = sf::Color::Green;

        Mywindow.draw(triangle);
    }
    catch( const std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cin.ignore();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cin.ignore();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The Makefile for compilation I am using is the following:

```
all:    exe

exe:    main.o
        g++ main.o -o exe -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

main.o: main.cpp
        g++ -c main.cpp
```

The follwing error is being displayed:

```
make
g++ -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:2: error: ‘VertexArray’ is not a member of ‘sf’
main.cpp:11:18: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘triangle’
main.cpp:13:2: error: ‘triangle’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:21:11: error: ‘class sf::RenderWindow’ has no member named ‘draw’
main.cpp:23:33: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
main.cpp:23:33: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
main.cpp:23:33: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘&’ token
main.cpp:23:35: error: ‘e’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:23:36: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I don't understand why it is saying VertexArray not member of sf!

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. Make sure you don't have two versions of SFML installed on your system.

Comment: I guess my system does not have full installation of SFML. Many header files are not there. Thanks anyway for replying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide a path to the SFML lib dir and a path to the SFML include dir.

Like this:

```
"-IC:\\Path\\to\\your\\project\\your-lib-sub-dir\\SFML-2.1\\include"
"-LC:\\Path\\to\\your\\project\\your-lib-sub-dir\\SFML-2.1\\lib"
```

Another thing, to be able to see something, you should suround your draw call with something like this:

```
while(1){
    Mywindow.clear(sf::Color::Black);
    Mywindow.draw(triangle);
    Mywindow.display();
}
```

Comment: I guess my system does not have full installation of SFML. Many header files are not there. Thanks anyway for replying!

Comment: Maybe [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21541442/1218980) on another SFML question may help you.