# 'sf::texture' not a member of 'sf'

Tags: sfml

Hey I just started tinkering with SFML. The line of code

```
sf::Texture texture;
```

causes the error:

```
game.cpp:12:2: error: ‘Texture’ is not a member of ‘sf’
  sf::Texture texture;
```

I feel like the directory /usr/includes/SFML/Graphics/ should contain a Texture.hpp file, Which it doesn't. Could that be it?

Comment: Your missing some information here. What SFML version are you using? It appears that you are trying to use SFML 2 code when you have SFML 1.6 (which has no `sf:Texture`) libraries installed.

Comment: I think you are right. How do I change it to 2.0?

Comment: Build and install from source. If your package manager doesn't provide an updated version, you're better off building from source than trying to find some pre-compiled binaries that then most likely link different versions of GLEW etc...

Comment: SFML 2.1 is the newest

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: The SFML [download](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php) page

If building from the source is overwhelming for you, that page provides a Linux build.

Or if building from the source is what you're aiming for, you'd better be taking the latest version from the Laurent Gomila's [SFML github repo](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML). This is the best option since you'll be enjoying fixes that are not included in the 2.1 version.